# MySql - How to get a list of date from month

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

How can I get the list of days from a given month and year?
I want to find the dates that are not in a list of dates from a selection...

For example, I have a list of dates like these:

```
tanggalKehadiran('06/01/2013','06/02/2013','06/03/2013','06/04/2013','06/27/2013',
    '06/28/2013','06/29/2013')
```

I want the output to be:

```
tanggalKehadiran('06/05/2013','06/06/2013','06/07/2013',.............,'06/24/2013',
    '06/25/2013','06/26/2013','06/30/2013')
```

Can I do this using a query?

Comment: those are not valid mysql date values, so you're stuck using string operations. Convert to native mysql date values, and then it's as simple as `DAY('2013-06-02') -> 02`. e.g. RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: sorry about the date format...X(
i mean if the format is right is there anyway in the query which allow me to get the missing dates from the a list of dates???

Comment: not really. sql isn't designed to produce data from nothing. you'd need to join against a list of numbers 1-31 and do a "NOT IN" type query to get the missing ones.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a table that contains all dates. You can then `JOIN` to this `date` table to complete missing dates. You can then use built-in date functions to perform any time of filtering.

Comment: making a tables that contains "all" dates???
but isn't that means that i have to make a lot of unnecessary data??
i have to store quite a lot of dates in the database...X(

Comment: You will be quite surprised to how much space this "unnecessary" data actually takes up and the long-term benefits.